# Running Multiple instances of an application in single tomcat container

Tags: tomcat, maven-3, web-deployment

I have already tried doing the following.

Created a context.xml per instance of the application and placed it in META-INF folder of the web application. This works perfectly fine.

I face a problem because I am trying to achieve the scenario where I deploy two different builds of the same application the only thing which varies is the **docBase** and I want to automate this. So that every time I don't need to manually edit the context file with the new build number.

But unfortunately when Maven writes the context.xml in the META-INF folder it doesn't replace the properties place holders with the real values.

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: My question is, " Please help me building my app so that I can create a context.xml in my project's META-INF, so that the property docBase is populated as maven's buildnumber"

Answer (score 0):

context.xml:

```
<Context docBase="/my/application/path/${buildNumber}"/>
```

and filter it with the resources plugin. You'll have to come up with the `buildNumber` somehow because maven doesn't provide it out of the box. The [build number plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) may help

Comment: this doesn't work. It places the context.xml file in the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF

I want the context.xml to be placed in META-INF :(

Comment: You can [use the `outputDirectory` property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) to change where the resources plugin places files.